# Regularity theory for parabolic PDEs in fractional Sobolev spaces

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, parabolic-pde, regularity

I am trying studying on my own parabolic PDEs throughout the book "Linear and Quasi-linear Equations of Parabolic Type" by Vsevolod A. Solonnikov, Nina Uraltseva, Olga Ladyzhenskaya and the existence and uniqueness of solutions for linear parabolic PDEs is proved for a fractional Sobolev space on page $320$:

> $\textbf{Theorem 5.1.}$ Suppose $l > 0$ is a nonintegral number and the coefficients of the operator $\mathcal{L}$ belongs to the class $H^{l,l/2} \left( \overline{D^{(T)}_{n+1}} \right)$, then for any $f \in H^{l,l/2} \left( \overline{D^{(T)}_{n+1}} \right), \ \phi \in H^{l + 2} \left( \overline{E}_n \right)$ problem $(5.2)$ has a unique solution from the class $H^{l/2,l/2+1} \left( \overline{D^{(T)}_{n+1}} \right)$. It satisfies the inequality
>
> $$|u|_{D^{(T)}_{n+1}}^{(l + 2)} \leq c \left( |f|_{D^{(T)}_{n+1}}^{(l)} + |\phi|_{E_n}^{(l + 2)} \right)$$
>
> with the constant not depending on $f$ and $\phi$.

I did not find that the solution in $H^{l,l/2} \left( \overline{D^{(T)}_{n+1}} \right)$ imply some regularity in the classical sense in the book.

I was looking for this in other sources I only find that the solution remains in $C^{0,\alpha}$ under the assumptions of the theorem $8.2$ on page $55$ of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.4345.pdf) lecture notes and remains in $C^{0,\beta}$ for $\beta < \alpha$ according the following corollary of the theorem $8.2$:

> $\textbf{Corollary 1.9}$ Let $s \in (0,1)$ and $p \in [1,+\infty)$ such that $sp > n$. Let $\Omega$ be a $C^{0,1}$ bounded domain  of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the embedding
>
> $$W^{s,p}(\Omega) \hookrightarrow C^{0,\beta}(\Omega)$$
>
> is compact for every $\beta < \alpha$ with $\alpha := \frac{sp - n}{p}$.

This corollary is on page $9$ of "Variational Methods for Nonlocal Fractional Problems" by Giovanni Molica Bisci, Vicentiu D. Radulescu, Raffaella Servadei.

I would like to some references to regularity theory for parabolic PDEs, i.e., results that prove that solutions in $H^{l,l/2} \left( \overline{D^{(T)}_{n+1}} \right)$ imply that the solution is classical. I also would like to know if there is some Schauder Theory for parabolic PDEs as in the item $(ii)$ of the theorem $4.5$ of [this](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pcma/1416323469) lecture.

Thanks in advance!